# getting an error of signed integer overflow(c++)

Tags: c++

please help me in resolving the error in below code:

```
int smallestRangeII(vector<int>& A, int k) {
        sort(A.begin(), A.end());
        int mini = INT_MAX;
        int maxi = INT_MIN;
        int x, y;
        int n = A.size();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            x = A[i]+k;
            y = A[i]-k;
            if(x <= A[n-1] && x<=maxi)
                maxi = x;
            else if(y>=A[0] && y>=mini)
                mini = y;
        }
        return (maxi - mini);
    }
```

I am getting an error of

> runtime error: signed integer overflow: -2147483648 - 2147483647
> cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp) SUMMARY:
> UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:27:22

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the line 27?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a signed integer where the value is the difference between the maximum and minimum integer values (that is possible for empty `A`). Even if `A` is not empty, there is no guarantee that `A` doesn't contain these extreme values. The value `INT_MAX - INT_MIN` is twice as large as the value the `int` type can represent.

One possible solution is to return an `unsigned int`:

```cpp
unsigned int smallestRangeII(vector<int>& A, int k);
```